# How to attribute a property from parent to the child in javascript? (OOP)

Tags: javascript, oop, object, extjs, touch

I'm developing a sencha touch application, and if a could do something like this, it would be great:

```
Ext.define('PUREM.view.screen.Form', {
    person : null,
    items : [
        {xtype: 'mycomponent', person: parent.person}
    ]
});
```

obviously this code doesn't work. I wanna know how to make it work, if is there a way to use the "person" property from parent object in a child object (xtype: 'mycomponent').

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: obviously this code doesn't work. I wanna know how to make it work, if  is there a way to use the "person" property from parent object in a child object (xtype: 'mycomponent').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class definition, you should override the `initComponent` function.  Then you will have access to all of the properties of the object.

```
Ext.define('PUREM.view.screen.Form', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        person : null
    },

    initComponent: function() 
    {
        var me = this;
        me.items = [
            {xtype: 'mycomponent', person: me.person}
        ]

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```